# Does Elastic Beanstalk support latest python version?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

In EB document it says Django 2.2 is incompatible with the Elastic Beanstalk Python 3.6 platform. The latest compatible version is Django 2.1.*https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html*

But another document says EB support latest python versions, don't they contradict each other ? I wish to try Django 2.2 *stable version* hosting.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of this writing (Nov 8, 2020), Amazon Elastic Beanstalk supports Python 3.7.9, as well as Python 3.6.12. The Python 3.6 AMI doesn’t support Django 2.2, however using the Python 3.7 AMI should work.

You can always find the currently supported versions across all platforms [on this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.python), which is the link you’ve already mentioned.

Comment: It seems that EB does not support latest version, will this be a good hosting plan then ?